# merging the inside elements of a list

Tags: python, string, list, intersection, cpu-word

I have two lists:

> a=[ 'ness' , 'ul' , 'ind' , 'be' ]

> b=[ 'kind ness' , 'ameri can' , 'ind ian' , 'be cause' , 'be lieve' , 'bo ring' ]

I want to write a program for comparing these lists and if the elements of list 'b' consist of the elements of list 'a', then the program merges it. for this example the output should be:

> output=[ 'kindness' , 'ameri can' , 'indian' , 'because' , 'believe' , 'bo ring' ]

I tried to find the intersection of two lists and then start merging but it didn't work. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Could you edit your post and explain more what you mean by '' elements of list 'b' consist of the elements of list 'a' " because there is a contradiction between this and your output

Comment: You can just split a value in output, then test if any one of the split values is in the `a` list.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English and thank you all for helping me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `set` along with list comprehension

```py
a=['ness','ul','ind','be']
b=['kind ness','ameri can','ind ian','be cause','be lieve','bo ring']

[i.replace(' ', '') if set(i.split(' ')).intersection(a) else i for i in b]
#['kindness', 'ameri can', 'indian', 'because', 'believe', 'bo ring']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
output = [(phrase.replace(' ', '') 
               if any(word in phrase for word in a) 
               else phrase
          ) for phrase in b]
# ['kindness', 'ameri can', 'indian', 'because', 'believe', 'bo ring']
```